# Google Sheets: Issue with ArrayFormula Concatenation Formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Title: Google Sheets: Issue with ArrayFormula Concatenation Formula

Hello,

I'm having an issue with my Google Sheets. I've created a matrix in one sheet and I'm using it in another sheet with an ArrayFormula to concatenate the result of the EQUIV() function with FormResponses. However, I'm not getting any results.

I use this formule : =ARRAYFORMULA(SOMME(RECHERCHEV(EQUIV('Réponses au formulaire 1'!C1:AK1;'Réponses au formulaire 1'!C1:AK1;0)&'Réponses au formulaire 1'!C2:AK2;parametres!C:D;2;FAUX)))
NOT WORKING:
[image]

You can find the link to the sheet I'm trying to modify here: [My Google Sheets Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BnEh63tnH1cexdCM4PZV8JFBSESuBcC76uJCnBOTdGo/edit?usp=sharing)

+

I except on sheets  [google sheets working expected](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-YJ1bt2XbZIaA0XfFhHbGBGJprAvC23Rwfx12x_7pqU/edit#gid=848377239): ArrayFormula(SOMME(RECHERCHEV(EQUIV(FormResponses!$D$1:$I$1,FormResponses!$D$1:$I$1,0)&FormResponses!D2:I2,SpiegelTable,2,FAUX))),"")
[image]

I followed the example in a LinkedIn post: [LinkedIn Post EN](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FME82FRIBsmNU8VADd6KyY2VeTjrQIdT/view?usp=share_link)
OR [LinkedIn Post FR](https://fr.linkedin.com/pulse/part-ii-google-forms-comment-calculer-un-score-comme-xavier-nesi)

Where could the issue be originating from? Do you have any leads?

Context:
I'm trying to calculate scores for 4 categories based on the [![matrix], with the goal of retrieving the 3 highest scores among the [![4 categories]

It 's works
I followed the example in a LinkedIn post: [LinkedIn Post](https://fr.linkedin.com/pulse/part-ii-google-forms-comment-calculer-un-score-comme-xavier-nesi)

Comment: Hi @antoinef,

Have you got an idea for this ?

Comment: `concatenate the result of the EQUIV() function` FYI, `EQUIV` (French language) == `MATCH`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your problem. You have referred to a matrix and form responses but you haven't explained EXACTLY what you are trying to do. You referenced an article on LinkedIn but that is in French, as is your spreadsheet. Would you please edit your question to provide sample data (for a matrix as well as form responses) as text in the body of the question, and also include an example of a successful outcome. You've obviously tried to implement the LinkedIn solution, so would you also include your "unsuccessful" formula (in context of sample data) in the question.

Comment: Thankx U. You're right. I'm correcting